# Parsley js with MVC5

Tags: jquery, data-annotations, asp.net-mvc-5, parsley.js

I am working on a MVC 5 project and i came across parsley.js and found it to be very interesting. I started working with that but soon enough I knew that we cannot integrate it with the data annotations we are usin in MVC.

The difference id=s that parsley expects "**data-required**" while the annotations gives "**data-val-required**".

How can i make both of them work with each other? Is there anyway in which we can influence the behaviour of either of them?

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The default namespace for parsley is 'parsley-', so required inputs would use 'parsley-required'. To change this to 'data-val-required' you would just need to override the namespace, which you can do as follows:

```
$('#formId').parsley({
    namespace: 'data-val-'
});
```

Comment: Just a note, if anyone else has trouble, instead of using 'data-val' this namespace worked for me: 'data-parsley-'